# progressbar is not displaying in title bar

Tags: android

I am using the following code, but my progress bar is not displaying in title bar instead displaying in my activiy top right corner

```
    <ProgressBar 
android:id="@+id/progress_bar" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"

android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

in code

```
//requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.welcome_layout);
```

Can any one plz help me out in this ..

Answer (score 2):

You should either create your own `ProgressBar` or use one in the title bar. So, in your case, you don't need this `ProgressBar` definition in the layout file. Just do the following:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); 
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```